# UITextView count lines not working as intended

Tags: uitextview, line, line-count

I'm trying to get the amount of lines in a `TextView`. I've searched here for a solution, basically every thread has the same answer : contentheight/fontlineheight.

I have a `TextView` with 8 lines, i run this code and i get `contsize : 1.944413`

```
NSLog(@"contsize : %f", descLabel.contentSize.height/descLabel.font.lineHeight);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS7, a version that take care that you can have differents font (and font size) in your UITextView :

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfLinesInTextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [textView layoutManager];
    NSUInteger index, numberOfLines;
    NSRange glyphRange = [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:[textView textContainer]];
    NSRange lineRange;

    for (numberOfLines = 0, index = glyphRange.location; index < glyphRange.length; numberOfLines++){
        (void) [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index
                                               effectiveRange:&lineRange];
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    }
    return numberOfLines;
}
```